Blazor Fluxor State Not Updating NavMenu Component on Role Change
Question:
I am working on a Blazor WebAssembly application using Fluxor for state management. I have a PersonCard component that allows users to select a role (Reader, Writer, Admin). Based on the selected role, the NavMenu component should dynamically display the relevant menu items.
The PersonCard component successfully dispatches the SelectRoleAction, and I can see the selected roles being logged in the console. However, the NavMenu component is not updating to reflect the selected role. It always shows all menu items, regardless of the selected role.
Here are the details of my implementation:
RoleState.cs
namespace UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
{
    public class RoleState
    {
        public string SelectedRole { get; }

        public RoleState() : this("All") { }

        public RoleState(string selectedRole)
        {
            SelectedRole = selectedRole;
        }

        public static RoleState CreateInitialState()
        {
            return new RoleState("All");
        }
    }
}


SelectRoleAction.cs
namespace UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
{
    public class SelectRoleAction
    {
        public string Role { get; }

        public SelectRoleAction(string role)
        {
            Role = role;
        }
    }
}


RoleReducer.cs
using Fluxor;

namespace UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
{
    public class RoleReducer : Reducer<RoleState, SelectRoleAction>
    {
        public override RoleState Reduce(RoleState state, SelectRoleAction action)
        {
            return new RoleState(action.Role);
        }
    }
}

RoleFeature.cs
using Fluxor;

namespace UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
{
    [FeatureState]
    public class RoleFeature : Feature<RoleState>
    {
        public override string GetName() => "Role";

        protected override RoleState GetInitialState() => RoleState.CreateInitialState();
    }
}


PersonCard.razor
@using Fluxor
@using UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
@inject IDispatcher Dispatcher

<MudCard Elevation="0" Square="true" Class="person-card" Style="@Style">
    <MudCardHeader>
        <CardHeaderAvatar>
            <MudAvatar Color="Color.Secondary">R</MudAvatar>
        </CardHeaderAvatar>
        <CardHeaderContent>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">Rohit</MudText>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.caption">Software Engineer</MudText>
        </CardHeaderContent>
    </MudCardHeader>

    <MudDivider Class="mb-2" />

    <MudListItem Text="Reader" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person" OnClick='() => SelectRole("Reader")' />
    <MudListItem Text="Writer" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person" OnClick='() => SelectRole("Writer")' />
    <MudListItem Text="Admin" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person" OnClick='() => SelectRole("Admin")' />

    <MudDivider Class="mt-2" />

    <div class="login-link">
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </div>
</MudCard>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Class { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? Style { get; set; }

    private void SelectRole(string role)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Role selected: {role}"); // Debugging output
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(new SelectRoleAction(role));
    }
}

NavMenu.razor
@using Fluxor
@using UIDesignRisk.Client.Store
@inject IState<RoleState> RoleState

<MudNavMenu>
    <MudNavLink Href="/" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Home">Home</MudNavLink>

    <p>Selected Role: @RoleState.Value.SelectedRole</p> <!-- Debugging output -->

    @if (RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "All" || RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "Reader")
    {
        <MudNavGroup Title="[INC] Report Security Incident" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PendingActions">
            <MudNavLink Href="/reportPhishing" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.BugReport">Report Phishing Attempt</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/reportIncident" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.GppBad">Report Security Incident</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/reportIssue" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.GppMaybe">Report a Security Issue</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/helpCenter" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.HelpCenter">Help Center</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>
    }

    @if (RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "All" || RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "Writer")
    {
        <MudNavGroup Title="[RSK] Risk Management" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddModerator">
            <MudNavLink Href="/mainRiskPage" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ChromeReaderMode">Main Page</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/approvals" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PendingActions">My Approvals & Actions</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/newRiskAssessment" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.NoteAdd">New Risk Assessments</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>
    }

    @if (RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "All" || RoleState.Value.SelectedRole == "Admin")
    {
        <MudNavGroup Title="[EXC] Exceptions Management" IconColor="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.WarningAmber">
            <MudNavLink Href="/mainExceptionPage" IconColor="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ChromeReaderMode">Main Page</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/myExceptionRecords" IconColor="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.PendingActions">My Approvals & Actions</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/newExceptionRequest" IconColor="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.NoteAdd">New Exception Request</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>

        <MudNavGroup Title="[A&R] Application & Resiliency" IconColor="Color.Warning" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AppRegistration">
            <MudNavLink Href="/mainResiliencyPage" IconColor="Color.Warning" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ChromeReaderMode">Main Page</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/appCriticality" IconColor="Color.Warning" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarHalf">Criticality Criteria Ratings</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Href="/bia" IconColor="Color.Warning" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ContentPaste">BIA</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>
    }
</MudNavMenu>


Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Fluxor;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UIDesignRisk.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            // Register MudBlazor services
            builder.Services.AddMudServices();

            // Configure Fluxor
            builder.Services.AddFluxor(options =>
                options.ScanAssemblies(typeof(Program).Assembly)
                       .UseRouting());

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}


App.razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using UIDesignRisk.Client.Shared
<Fluxor.Blazor.Web.StoreInitializer />
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
}

Problem Description:

The PersonCard component correctly dispatches the SelectRoleAction, and the selected roles are logged in the console.
Despite the SelectRoleAction being dispatched, the NavMenu component does not update to reflect the selected role. It always shows all menu items.
The expected behavior is that the NavMenu component should dynamically display menu items based on the selected role.

Debugging Information:
The Role selected:  message appears correctly in the console when a role is selected.
The Selected Role: @RoleState.Value.SelectedRole in the NavMenu component always shows "All".
Additional Debug Outputs
I added debugging outputs to NavMenu.razor:
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Role: {RoleState.Value.SelectedRole}");
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Parameters Set Role: {RoleState.Value.SelectedRole}");
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}


What I've Tried
Ensured the state, actions, reducers, and features are correctly defined.
Verified that the action is dispatched and the state is updated.
Added debug outputs to verify the current state in the NavMenu component.
Question
Why is the NavMenu component not updating based on the selected role, and how can I ensure that the state change is propagated correctly to update the menu items dynamically?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
